# Qual é a finalidade das constantes INPHINIT_START, INPHINIT_ROOT, INPHINIT_PATH e INPHINIT_COMPOSER?

Tags: php, inphinit

Estou estudando a respeito do micro-framework [Inphinit](http://inphinit.github.io/). E no arquivo index.php estão declaradas algumas constantes que me deixou confuso a respeito de suas finalidades.

Código do index.php:

```
define('INPHINIT_START', microtime(true));
define('INPHINIT_ROOT', rtrim(strtr(dirname(__FILE__), '\\', '/'), '/') . '/');
define('INPHINIT_PATH', INPHINIT_ROOT . 'system/');
define('INPHINIT_COMPOSER', false);
```

## Perguntas

Eu gostaria de saber a finalidade das seguintes constantes:

- constante `INPHINIT_START`
- constante `INPHINIT_ROOT`
- constante `INPHINIT_PATH`
- constante `INPHINIT_COMPOSER`

Também eu gostaria de saber qual importância de cada uma em relação ao funcionamento da minha aplicação Web?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basicamente elas são usadas como pré-configurações do framework todo, com exceção da `INPHINIT_START` que tem outro propósito (esta irei citar por último).

### Constantes para configuração

- `INPHINIT_ROOT`:

  É usada para apontar qual o diretório você deseja usar como root do seu projeto, geralmente deve ser o mesmo local de onde estiver o `index.php`

  > **Nota:** no código padrão usei o `strtr` para trocar `\`  por `/` e o `rtrim` para remover barras adicionais que vierem a mais a direita, é que existem alguns casos de variações de resultados em versões diferentes do PHP que provavelmente foram corrigidas, mas as vezes um servidor por usar uma versão PATCH mais antiga, por exemplo na versão 5.6.18 foi corrigido, mas o problema o servidor por algum motivo ainda usa a versão 5.6.17. Note que PHP não é o unico interpretador de scripts PHP, também existe o HHVM que interpreta, a ideia é garantir que não ocorram diferenças de resultados entre diferente sistemas e versões
- `INPHINIT_PATH`:

  Este deve apontar a pasta `system`, se você desejar customizar a estrutura de pastas você pode trocar o valor desta constante, por exemplo se quiser colocar o index.php dentro de uma pasta chamada `public` e a `system` fora dela, você poderá faz assim:

  ```
  define('INPHINIT_PATH', INPHINIT_ROOT . '../system/');
  ```
- `INPHINIT_COMPOSER`:

  O inphinit usa o composer para gerenciar os pacotes que você deseja instalar adicionais ao seu projeto, mas não usa por padrão o [composer-autoload](/questions/tagged/composer-autoload), ele usa o [`UtilsAutoload()`](https://github.com/inphinit/framework/blob/master/src/Utils.php#L117), na pratica ambos são iguais, no entanto o `UtilsAutoload()` é um pouco mais eficiente, claro que pode haver algo que funcione só especificamente no `composer-autoload`, então como garantia deixei a opção de poder alternar, para usar o `composer-autoload` é só definir como `true`:

  ```
  define('INPHINIT_COMPOSER', true);
  ```

---

### A constante `INPHINIT_START`

Esta constante não tem finalidade alguma para o funcionamento do framework (com exceção da classe [`Inphinit\Experimental\Debug`](https://github.com/inphinit/framework/blob/master/src/Experimental/Debug.php#L191), que é uma classe usada para o desenvolvimento), a unica utilidade dela é para você poder fazer testes de "performance" (ou melhor tempo que levou para ser executado), por exemplo imagine que você quer fazer algo semelhante ao buscador do Google:

> [image: google]

Você pode fazer algo assim:

```
<?php

use Inphinit\Routing\Route;

Route::set('GET', '/exemplo', function () {
    return 'Olá mundo! Sua página levou: ' . round(microtime(true) - INPHINIT_START, 4) . ' segundos';
});
```

E resultará nisto:

> [image: tempo de resposta]

Claro que é apenas um exemplo e o foco não é este especificamente. Quanto a usar a classe `Inphinit\Experimental\Debug`, é relativamente simples, basta alterar o `system/dev.php` e adicionar isto (em modo DEBUG):

```
<?php
use Inphinit\Experimental\Debug;

Debug::view('error', 'debug.error');

//              ^-- ação     ^-- nome da View

Debug::view('performance', 'debug.performance');

//              ^-- ação     ^-- nome da View
```

> Os comentários são somente para exeplicar

Todas as páginas exibirão algo como isto no rodapé:

[image: debug]

Se a `INPHINIT_START` não estivesse definida adequadamente provavelmente iria obter um valor inesperado.

> Note que `'debug.performance'` se refere ao `system/application/View/debug/performance.php`, o qual você pode customizar:
>
> ```
> <div class="box">
>     <h1>Perfomance</h1>
>     <p>Memory usage: <?php echo $usage; ?></p>
>     <p>Memory peak: <?php echo $peak; ?></p>
>     <p>Memory usage real: <?php echo $real; ?></p>
>     <p>Time: <?php echo $time; ?></p>
> </div>
> ```